# mysql fulltext multiple words from one form input?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I've heared alot of similar discussion but I havent seen a direct solution.

```
SELECT * FROM patient_db WHERE 
       MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('%$term%' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Isn't there something simple around my '%$term%' I need to do to enable multiple-word searching?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to directly say, "I want one of these `n` words" in a MySQL fulltext query. Your only real option is

```
SELECT * FROM patient_db WHERE 
       MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('%$term%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('%$term2%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('%$term3%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       ;
```

Just curious, but why are you searching a column named `id_number` for text?

Comment: I want to provide a simply ui for our staff that can search for Name, or ID number - I'm not too savvy with mySQL yet, one word works fine, but two words "firstname lastname" hasnt worked yet